# asp:dropDownList selecting on value rather than key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm binding data into an asp:DropDownList like so:

```
MyDDL.DataSource = DAL.GetKeyValuePairs();
MyDDL.DataTextField = "Key";
MyDDL.DataValueField = "Value";
MyDDL.DataBind();
```

In my html I've got the list defined like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList
    runat="server"
    ID="MyDDL"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    Visible="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True"
    ViewStateMode="Enabled"
    EnableViewState="True" />
```

The problem is that if I select a key from my drop down list where the value is a duplicate of another value, then the dropdown automatically selects the first instance of a key that has that value, instead of just selecting the key!

For example:

The dropDownList shows

```
Key1
Key2
Key3
Key4
```

The values associated with the keys are:

```
Key1 - value1
Key2 - value2
Key3 - value3
Key4 - value3 (notice this last value is the same as for key3)
```

So when I choose "Key4" from the dropDownList, it *actually selects Key3* for me.

Why does this happen? Is another part of the code responsible for this or is it just how dropDownLists work?! When I pull in the `.DataSource` my data is being returned correctly. I can see the correct key/value pairs, it's just I'm not being allowed to select certain keys on the front-end?!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make each item of your list have a unique id?

Comment: If you are selecting from a dropdown, why would you have two entries with the same value? Perhaps you should consider consolidating multiple entries with the same value into a single entry? The `DataTextField` property holds an arbitrary text value and as such, cannot be reliably used for matching. The `DataValueField` property on the other hand is expected to represent your selection.

Comment: The question is not clear, post an example of the given data, and what you are expecting.

Comment: @Isma, I believe they do, isn't that what the KEY is for?

Comment: @JuanR The dropdown list should all be unique, they show all unique, but different keys should be able to have the same value.

Comment: @mxmissile I've added a simple example.

Comment: P.S I've inherited this code from god-knows-where. I'm sure it's not setup properly because it seems to be identifying things on the "value" rather than the "key" but I can't figure out why?

Comment: So it occurs to me that if `.DataTextField` is arbitrary text and `.DataValueField` is the identifier then maybe I just need to swap them round and display them differently on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataTextField` property specifies the source from which the text of your list item will be displayed.

The `DataValueField` property specifies the source from which the list item will retrieve the value for each element (the value is a unique key for each item).

So, although it is a bit confusing, I think the mapping with your `KeyValuePair` class would be the opposite as you are doing it, try:

```
MyDDL.DataTextField = "Value";
MyDDL.DataValueField = "Key";
```

Comment: Yup I think whoever wrote it made this assumption and then built on it to display things in other areas of the page. It'll take some refactoring but by swapping at this level I think it'll work.

Comment: Glad it is solved, if you want to use the value as the key you could too but you would need to make a choice and discard duplicates which doesn't seem right in this case. I think they key is the value and the value the key ;-)

Comment: This didn't quite do the trick because the display needs to come from the key of a dictionary object. If I swap it, then the value is displayed and is super long. I ended up storing the dictionary in a private field, setting both `MyDDL.DataTextField` AND `MyDDL.DataValueField` to "Key" and then pulling the value from the source to show in the necessary display areas.

Comment: Yeah that was impossible to know from your question, but the problem was in fact related to the DataTextField and DataValueField it seems.